# Слияние отрезков

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

На входе есть список отрезков какой-то (непрерывной) оси (числовой или временной, не важно), каждый отрезок представлен парой (упорядоченных) координат — начало и конец (эти точки также принадлежат отрезку).

Необходимо слить все пересекающиеся отрезки и получить на выходе список отрезков не имеющих пересечений (но этот новый список не должен иметь точки, которых не было в отрезках на входе).

Например, имеем на входе:

```
[1; 5]
[2; 4]
[7; 9]
[3; 6]
```

тогда, на выходе необходимо получить:

```
[1; 6] // здесь слиты [1; 5], [2; 4], [3; 6]
[7; 9]
```

реализовал алгоритм примерно такой:

```js
function merge(segments) {
  while (true) {
    const newSegments = [];
    for (const x of segments) {
      let found = false;
      for (const y of newSegments) {
        if (x.end >= y.start && x.start <= y.end) {
          y.start = Math.min(y.start, x.start);
          y.end = Math.max(y.end, x.end);
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found) newSegments.push(x);
    }
    if (segments.length == newSegments.length) break;
    segments = newSegments;
  }
  return segments;
}

function print(segments) {
  console.log(segments.map(s => `[${s.start}; ${s.end}]`).join(' '));
}

let segments = [
  { start: 1, end: 5 },
  { start: 2, end: 4 },
  { start: 7, end: 9 },
  { start: 3, end: 6 }
];

print(segments);
print(merge(segments));
```

Он работает, но имеет сложность O(n³).
Можно ли написать решение лучше?

Есть идея: отсортировать входной список и как-то адаптировать метод сканирующей прямой; но как это реализовать пока не могу придумать.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Сортировка по левой точке - это правильный первый шаг, получаем:

```
[1; 5]
[2; 4]
[3; 6]
[7; 9]
```

Далее сравниваем первый отрезок со вторым - начало второго попадает в первый отрезок, значит сливаем отрезки: началом будет начало первого, а концом - max(конец первого, конец второго), получаем `[1; 5]`.

```
[1; 5]
[3; 6]
[7; 9]
```

Так же сливаем `[1; 5]` и `[3; 6]` в `[1; 6]`

```
[1; 6]
[7; 9]
```

`[1; 6]` и `[7; 9]` не пересекаются, значит фиксируем `[1; 6]` с ним уже никакой другой отрезок не пересечется, и повторяем все действия начиная с `[7; 9]`

сложность сортировки `O(n log(n))`, сложность слияния `O(n)` итого `O(n log(n))`

Answer (score 2):

Получилось в итоге так:

```js
function merge(segments) {
  if (segments.length === 0) return [];
  const inp = segments.map(s => ({...s}));
  inp.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start);
  const out = [];
  let s = inp[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < inp.length; ++i) {
    if (inp[i].start <= s.end) {
      s.end = Math.max(s.end, inp[i].end);
    } else {
      out.push(s);
      s = inp[i];
    }
  }
  out.push(s);
  return out;
}

function print(segments) {
  console.log(segments.map(s => `[${s.start}; ${s.end}]`).join(' '));
}

let segments = [
  { start: 1, end: 5 },
  { start: 2, end: 4 },
  { start: 7, end: 9 },
  { start: 3, end: 6 }
];

print(segments);
print(merge(segments));
```

Answer (score 1):

больше от скуки запилил решение на C#

```
public class Solution
{
    public int[][] Merge(int[][] intervals)
    {
        if (intervals == null || intervals.Length == 0) return new int[0][];

        Array.Sort(intervals, 0, intervals.Length, new IntervalComparer());
        var stack = new Stack<int[]>();

        var curr = intervals[0];

        for(int i=1; i<intervals.Length; i++)
        {           
            var next = intervals[i];                
            if (curr[1] >= next[0])                         
                curr = new int[] {curr[0], Math.Max(curr[1], next[1])};
            else 
            {
                stack.Push(curr);
                curr = next;                    
            }
        }           
        stack.Push(curr);

        var ret = new int[stack.Count][];
        for(int i = ret.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
            ret[i] = stack.Pop();

        return ret;
    }

    private class IntervalComparer : IComparer<int[]>
    {
        public int Compare(int[] x, int[] y)
        {
            return x[0].CompareTo(y[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код побил 99.7% решений [этой задачи](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/) на leetcode (решений на C#)

Comment: Ага, ну это один в один то что я написал :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP так у тебя верное решение, да и задачу сложно решить как то по другому, потому любой, кто ее решит эффективно напишет точно такой же код (глянь решения на том же leetcode, там в топе примерно один и тот же код)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const merge = ss => {
  ss = ss.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start)
  let c = ss.shift()
  const m = [c]
  ss.forEach(s => (s.start <= c.end) ? (s.end > c.end) && (c.end = s.end) : m.push(c = s))
  return m
}

console.log(merge([
  { start: 1, end: 5 },
  { start: 2, end: 4 },
  { start: 7, end: 9 },
  { start: 3, end: 6 }
]))
```

Comment: Ага, это в точности что и у меня, но портит исходный массив и портит исходные объекты. У меня если после `print(merge(segments));` вызвать ещё раз `print(segments);`, то выведет что и первый вызов, у вас же будет выведено что-то другое